# Exporting fa ile into delimited file in sas

Tags: sas

I'm able to export the data with the expected delimiter but there is no column name in the exported file

```
FILENAME outfile '/SASData/download.txt';
DATA _NULL_;
   SET download;
   FILE outfile dlmstr="~|" ;
  RUN;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not writing anything to the file.  You have no PUT statement at all.

To write all of the data you just need to add a PUT statement using a variable list with a format list.

```
put (_all_) (+0) ;
```

But if you also want to include a header row with the variable names you will have to do a little more work.  One easy way to write the line with the names first then use the MOD option of the file statement in the step that writes the actual data.

Here is an example using SASHELP.CLASS.

```
proc transpose data=sashelp.class(obs=0) out=names ;
  var _all_;
run;

data _null_;
  file outfile dlmstr='~|';
  set names;
  put _name_ @ ;
run;

data _null_;
  set sashelp.class ;
  file outfile dlmstr='~|' mod;
  put (_all_) (+0) ;
run;
```

Result

```
905  data _null_;
906    infile outfile;
907    input;
908    put _infile_;
909  run;

NOTE: The infile OUTFILE is:
      (system-specific pathname),
      (system-specific file attributes)

Name~|Sex~|Age~|Height~|Weight
Alfred~|M~|14~|69~|112.5
Alice~|F~|13~|56.5~|84
Barbara~|F~|13~|65.3~|98
Carol~|F~|14~|62.8~|102.5
Henry~|M~|14~|63.5~|102.5
James~|M~|12~|57.3~|83
Jane~|F~|12~|59.8~|84.5
Janet~|F~|15~|62.5~|112.5
Jeffrey~|M~|13~|62.5~|84
John~|M~|12~|59~|99.5
Joyce~|F~|11~|51.3~|50.5
Judy~|F~|14~|64.3~|90
Louise~|F~|12~|56.3~|77
Mary~|F~|15~|66.5~|112
Philip~|M~|16~|72~|150
Robert~|M~|12~|64.8~|128
Ronald~|M~|15~|67~|133
Thomas~|M~|11~|57.5~|85
William~|M~|15~|66.5~|112
NOTE: 20 records were read from the infile (system-specific pathname).
      The minimum record length was 21.
      The maximum record length was 30.
```